# Rehashing Existing Passwords That Were Hashed With An Outdated Function

Tags: security, hash, passwords

We've got a legacy system that stores passwords using the MS membership provider and have just found out that it only used a SHA1 with a random salt to store the passwords, so obviously we are concerned about this situation.  I know the ideal situation would be to force a global password reset, but for assorted reasons we would like to avoid this, if possible, and keep the existing passwords as-is.  I've done some poking around and have managed to find some source-code, and can re-hash my password so I get the same result as the stored version of it, so I am wanting to override all the appropriate methods to reimplement the code in a secure manner.

What I am proposing to do is to rehash the stored passwords using a currently "secure" hash (AFAIK, the current methods are only classed as secure due to the amount of computation time it takes to brute-force a password, so if systems get a big performance upgrade the whole programming world could end up having to revisit this), then wrap this hash around the existing hash in the code, but I have 2 questions:-

Is this actually secure?  As far as I have read, each hash needs to increase the amount of entropy and I'm 90% sure this will do so, but are there any issues in doing this that I need to be aware of?  I'm also guessing that in chains of hashing it's the strongest hash function that determines the "base-line" security level, but I thought I'd double-check there weren't any weird mathematical quirks with hashing an "insecure" hash.  I'm sure not, but due to the nature of the problem, I'd rather ask a stupid question than make any incorrect assumptions, as the technical aspect of hashing functions isn't something I've really looked into.

Should I re-apply the salt to the current hash, before re-hashing.  My thinking on this was in case there were existing calculated tables which convert older hashes to newer ones - in case someone nefarious had done the grunt-work to try to bypass this method.  I believe b-crypt may already include a salt, but if I use an alternative that doesn't, I'm guessing should include one?

Answer (score 2):

Double hashing can be a good way to protect very weak password-hashes immediately, if you can't wait on the next user login and don't want to enforce a login. Weak password-hashes include unsalted hashes or very fast hashes like SHA-*/MD5.

So you can prepare your database like this:

1. Make the old salt persistent in the database, you need the `oldSalt` to verify the double hash.
2. Calculate the double hash and store it in the database `newHash = newSafeHashFunction(oldHash, newSalt)`. Nowadays safe hash functions are BCrypt, SCrypt, Argon2 and PBKDF2. Generate a new salt fullfilling the requirements of the new password-hash function.
3. After the next successful login, the double hash should be replaced with the pure new algorithm `newSafeHashFunction(password, newSalt)`.

Most password-hash implementations will generate a safe salt on their own and include it in the resulting password-hash string, so there is no need to generate and store them separately. When the user logs in the next time, the password can be verified like this:

```
if (checkIfDoubleHash(storedHash))
  correctPassword = newSafeHashFunction(oldUnsafeHashFunction(password, oldSalt), storedHash)
else
  correctPassword = newSafeHashFunction(password, storedHash)
```

➽ Note the function `checkIfDoubleHash()`, it is crucial and a common pitfall for double hashing. If we would generally accept `newSafeHashFunction(password, storedHash)` and an attacker can get hold of an old backup, or has values from an earlier SQL-injection, (s)he could use the old hashes directly as password.

The implementation of `checkIfDoubleHash()` can be as easy as checking for the old salt, or it can be made future proof in marking the hash as double hash. Most frameworks already offer a `password_hash()` function which adds such a "mark", so they can switch to newer algorithms when necessary.

```
$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
 |
 hash-algorithm-descriptor = 2y = BCrypt
```

This is an often adopted format used by the Unix [crypt()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)) function. There is nothing preventing you from using your own descriptor for the double hashes. Of course the mark can also be stored in a separate database field.